# JavaFX: Unrecognized option: --add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jpackage

I developed a ***JavaFX*** application and through ***JPackage*** I created the installation package.
When I try to click on the * .exe startup file of my application I get the error:

```
Unrecognized option: --add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Here is my configuration:

1. **S.O.** Windows10
2. **java**

   java version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86, mixed mode, sharing)
3. **Jpackage** version 17.0.1

These are the steps to create the installation package:

1. Create FAT Jar with Maven:

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.8.1</version>
           <configuration>
               <source>17</source>
               <target>17</target>
               <annotationProcessorPaths>
                   <path>
                       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                       <version>1.18.22</version>
                   </path>
               </annotationProcessorPaths>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.0</version>
           <configuration>
               <archive>
                   <manifest>
                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                       <mainClass>Launcher</mainClass>
                   </manifest>
               </archive>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.0</version>
           <configuration>
               <descriptorRefs>
                   <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
               </descriptorRefs>
               <archive>
                   <manifest>
                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                       <mainClass>com.merkury.Launcher</mainClass>
                   </manifest>
               </archive>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                   <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                   <goals>
                       <goal>single</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
           <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.8</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                   <id>default-cli</id>
                   <configuration>
                       <mainClass>com.merkury.Launcher</mainClass>
                       <options>
                           <option>--add-exports</option>
                           <option>javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls</option>
                       </options>
                       <launcher>app</launcher>
                       <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                       <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                       <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                       <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                       <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. Create a Custom Runtime Image

   ```
   jlink --output install/windows/merkury --module-path "D:\Program Files\javafx-jmods-17.0.2" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,java.sql,java.logging
   ```
3. Launch Jpackage

   ```
   jpackage --input target --name Merkury --main-jar Mercury-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar --main-class com.merkury.Launcher --description "Software gestionale per i medici del lavoro" --vendor "Nvsecurity.it" --icon install/assets/merkury.ico --dest install/output --app-version 1.0 --runtime-image install/windows/merkury --win-shortcut --win-dir-chooser --win-menu --win-menu-group "Nvsecurity Merkury" --type exe --java-options "'--add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls'" --win-console
   ```

In my application I need to use ***AutoCompletionBinding*** and as stated [here](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/wiki/Using-ControlsFX-with-JDK-9-and-above) I had to add the option for the VM as java-options of Jpackage:

```
--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening? Thank you

**EDIT 05-03-22**

> Do you need both double and single quotes to supply the add-exports
> option to jpackage?

Yes As described [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/support-application-features.html#GUID-34C3BE72-CDE5-469B-BC4D-3D9A6DD2AEEA)

> Perhaps try using JPackageScriptFX

I tried to package and deploy the indicated project. Adding the option

```
  --java-options "'--add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls'"^
```

doesn't work. Without it works.

Comment: Do you need both double *and* single quotes to supply the add-exports option to jpackage? (I don’t know, just double check it though). Do you need to create a fat jar?  What is in the fat jar?  It would not make sense to include JavaFX dependencies in the fat jar given you are already linking the modules into the runtime.

Comment: Perhaps try using [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX). Try to get the samples from that project to work in your environment. Then either apply what you learned to your project or adapt your project to work with those scripts rather than the packaging setup you are currently using.

Comment: To respond to comments, it may be best to edit the question, to add additional info, quoting comments.